# 16.04 gnome interface scaling

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome, 4k-monitor

I have a laptop with a 4k monitor and Ubuntu looks fine as it detects it and auto scales the UI. However some other apps are way to small in 4k so I set my resolution to 1080.

At first everything is still scaled up but going to the tweak tool and adjust the font scaling from 1 to 0.9 and back again sorts the scaling out and everything looks fine.

However after rebooting Ubuntu seems to do some auto detection again and apply the UI scaling for 4k even though the resolution is now 1080.

Does anyone know what this process is and how to disable the auto scaling it applys?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to stop this behavior by switching from gnome classic back to the current gnome on the login screen.

After making this change my system no longer automatically enlarges on UI login when it does not need to and everything looks fine.